# Dual-boot more than two operating systems

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, debian, multi-boot

I currently run Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 as a dual-boot system. I need Linux, but Ubuntu freezes at least once a day. So I want to replace it with another distribution like Debian or LMDE. On the other hand I am a little concerned that I'll have troubles working with a less user friendly operating system than Ubuntu. 
So would it be possible to just scale down the Windows partition and install the next Linux as a third system? Thus, with a "triple-boot system" I could keep Ubuntu until I feel familiar with the new system.
Afterwards, I guess, it should be possible to replace the Ubuntu partition by expanding the new system?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 was release yesterday. Give it a shot.

Comment: kiloseven is right, but be careful. When you resize the windows partition, there is a chance you may lose your data. Resizing a partition is an inherently dangerous process. Do yourself a favor, back-up all of your data before the beginning of this operation. And, BTW, you should open a post to try to clarify why your Ubuntu freezes, it simply shouldn't.

Comment: Backup, backup, backup !   MM is absolutely right !

Comment: Ok I gave it a try, in principal it worked and I lost no data. On the other hand I rediscovered the messy partitioning that already existed before, since at that time I did not dare to change the partitioning of the pre-installed Windows. I will now remove all the unused files from the Windows partition and after a new backup reinstall Win+Debian(+Ubuntu) in a clean organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, YES. GRUB and GRUB2 accommodate multiple OS.    http://www.pagestart.com/win7heptaboot01.html has more info, as does https://askubuntu.com/questions/351002/triple-boot-ubuntu-windows-showing-up-but-not-red-hat